# Efficiently split a long document into multiple shorter documents based on whitespace characters and specified character length

Tags: python, performance

I need to write a function to split long documents into shorter documents on whitespace characters (`\s`) based on pre-specified character length.

To illustrate, for example, I have a text document that has 175,000,000 characters (including all the punctuation and whitespace characters). I would like to split the document into shorter documents of roughly 100,000 characters each.

Of course, the spots where splits happen won't be exactly at the 100,000th/200,00th/300,000th... characters because a whitespace character might not be exactly at those spots. If a whitespace character is not at the desired splitting point (e.g., if the 100,000th character is not a whitespace character), the function will look for the closest whhitespace character to **the left** and split there. The following is my attempt at the function, but it seems that the function is very slow.

```
whitespace_regex = re.compile(r"\s")

def foo(text):
    # If a document is 100000 character long or shorter
    # no splitting is needed
    if len(text) <= 100000:
        yield text
    # Splitting if a document is longer than 100000 characters
    elif len(text) > 100000:
        # A while loop until there is nothing left to be split
        while len(text) > 100000:
            # Split a document into two segments: 
            #     left: 100000 character long
            #     text: the rest of the document
            left, text = text[:100000], text[100000:]

            # Look for the rightmost whitespace character in the 'left'
            # segment by first reversing the string so that the whitespace
            # returned by the regex search is the rightmost whitespace
            whitespace = whitespace_regex.search(left[::-1])

            # Get the start index of the returned whitespace. If -index
            # is 0, then that means pro
            index = whitespace.start()
            index = -index
            # if the whitespace is not exactly at the desired position,
            # yield the part to the left of the whitespace character, and
            # combine the part of the left segment to the right of the
            # whitespace character with the rest of the remaining text
            if index < 0:
                text = left[index:] + text
                left = left[:index]
            yield left
        if text:
            yield text
```

I tested the speed on a document with 175,000,000 characters, and it took almost 6 minutes to finish splitting the document:

```
a = "John did what others told him to do" * 5000000
print(f"Document's length is {len(a)}")
#Document's length is 175000000

start_time = time.time()
segs = [x for x in foo(a)]
print(time.time() - start_time)
#344.3530957698822
```

**I wonder if there is a way to write a much more efficient function to do this.**

Comment: You could try splitting on *all* the `whitespace_regex `matches first (using `re.split`), and then recombining items of the resulting list until so you have segments of the desired length.

Comment: @SimonR I would like to preserve the different types of whitespace characters inside each shorter document. If i do `re.split`, they won't be preserved? -- Like I know where the whitespace characters occur, but i don't know exactly which whitespace character they are

Answer (score 0):

The problem scales very badly with the size of a document. For example, 10 times smaller document ran on my machine in `0.3` seconds, your size did so in `144.8`. I think the problem is that every time you chop off a chunk from the left, the remaining text moved. So one solution could be to actually start chopping your document from the back. Another solution could be just chop the array in smaller blocks and run the function on them:

```
a = "John did what others told him to do" * 5000000
print(f"Document's length is {len(a)}")
#Document's length is 1750000000

start_time = time()
segs = []
block_size = 17500000
start_ind = 0
num_blocks = int(len(a)/block_size) + 1
for i in range(num_blocks):
  if len(a)-start_ind > block_size:
      block = a[start_ind : start_ind + block_size]
  else:
      block = a[start_ind :]

  block_segs = [x for x in foo(block)]

  start_ind += block_size - len(block_segs[-1])

  segs += block_segs[:-1]
  if len(a)-start_ind > block_size: segs += block_segs[-1]


print(time() - start_time)
```

This takes about `3.0` seconds. Fast and dirty, I suppose...